# FTPS storeFile return always false Java

Tags: java, ftp-client, ftps

im trying to send files to FTPS server
connection method: FTPS, ACTIVE, EXPLICIT

```
setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
setFileTransferMode(FTP.BLOCK_TRANSFER_MODE);
```

Checking the reply string right after connect i got:

```
234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.
```

from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes)

```
 234    Specifies that the server accepts the authentication mechanism specified by the client, and the exchange of security data is complete. A higher level nonstandard code created by Microsoft.
```

while trying to send file with storeFile  or storeUniqeFile i get false

checking the reply string right after store file i got: `501 Server cannot accept argument.`

what is weird i was able creating a directory to this client without any issues
with `makeDirectory("test1");`

i was trying both this links : [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154115/ftpclient-storefile-always-return-false) , [link2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/324f30a0-3740-4260-9eb5-349274c3351d/ftp-501-server-cannot-accept-argument?forum=iispublishing)

FOR EXAMPLE when i was trying `to use ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode(); before ftp.storeFile(destinationfile, in);`
i got time out error .

Does anyone have any idea how to solve it ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    FTPSProvider ftps = new FTPSProvider();
    String json =    "connection details";
    DeliveryDetailsFTPS details = gson.fromJson(json, DeliveryDetailsFTPS .class);
    File file = File.createTempFile("test", ".txt");
    FileUtils.write(file, " some test", true);
    try (FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        ftps.sendInternal(ftps.getClient(details), details, stream, file.getName());
    }
}




protected void sendInternal(FTPClient client, DeliveryDetailsFTPS  details, InputStream stream, String filename) throws Exception {

    try {
        // release the enc
        DeliveryDetailsFTPS ftpDetails = (DeliveryDetailsFTPS) details;
        setClient(client, ftpDetails);
        boolean isSaved = false;
        try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(stream)) {
            isSaved = client.storeFile(filename, bis);
        }
        client.makeDirectory("test1");
        client.logout();
        if (!isSaved) {
            throw new IOException("Unable to upload file to FTP");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.debug("Unable to send to FTP", ex);
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        client.disconnect();
    }
}




@Override
protected FTPClient getClient(DeliveryDetails details) {
    return new FTPSClient(isImplicitSSL((DeliveryDetailsFTPS ) details));
}

    protected void setClient(FTPClient client, DeliveryDetailsFTPS details) throws Exception {
        DeliveryDetailsFTPS ftpDetails = (DeliveryDetailsFTPS ) details;
        client.setConnectTimeout(100000);
        client.setDefaultTimeout(10000 * 60 * 2);
         
            client.setControlKeepAliveReplyTimeout(300);
         
              client.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(300);
     
        client.setDataTimeout(15000);
        client.connect(ftpDetails.host, ftpDetails.port);
        client.setBufferSize(1024 * 1024);
        client.login(ftpDetails.username, ftpDetails.getSensitiveData());
        client.setControlEncoding("UTF-8");

        int code = client.getReplyCode();
        if (code == 530) {
            throw new IOException(client.getReplyString());
        }

        // Set binary file transfer
        client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        client.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BLOCK_TRANSFER_MODE);

        if (ftpDetails.ftpMode == FtpMode.PASSIVE) {
            client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        }

         client.changeWorkingDirectory(ftpDetails.path);
    }
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453716/android-ftp-file-tranfer-over-explicit-tls) solution as well didn't solve the problem:

they only way i was able send file is with FileZilla and it is using FTPES .
But i need my Java code to do it . can anyone give me a clue

Comment: I think we need an MCVE for this.  The 234 response code is saying that the TLS negotiation has not taken place, and see need to see the code and be able to run it to understand why.

Comment: This explains: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried almost any possible solution offered on different websites could not make it work with Apache FTPS CLIENT , 
had to use a different class which worked like a charm here is a snippet:

[com.jscape.inet.ftps Link](http://files.jscape.com/sftp/docs/javadoc/com/jscape/inet/ftps/Ftps.html)

```
private Ftps sendWithFtpsJSCAPE(ConnDetails details, InputStream stream, String filename) throws FtpException, IOException {
    Ftps ftp;
    FtpConnectionDetails ftpDetails = FtpConnectionDetails details;

    ftp = new Ftps(ftpDetails.getHost(), ftpDetails.getUsername(), ftpDetails.getPassword());



    if (ftpDetails.getSecurityMode().equals(FtpConnectionDetails.SecurityMode.EXPLICIT)) {
        ftp.setConnectionType(Ftps.AUTH_TLS);
    } else {
        ftp.setConnectionType(Ftps.IMPLICIT_SSL);
    }
    ftp.setPort(ftpDetails.getPort());

    if (!ftpDetails.getFtpMode().equals(FtpMode.ACTIVE)) {
        ftp.setPassive(true);
    }
    ftp.setTimeout(FTPS_JSCAPE_TIME_OUT);
    ftp.connect();
    ftp.setBinary();
    ftp.setDir(ftpDetails.getPath());
    ftp.upload(stream, filename);

    return ftp;
}
```